# Do I need to drop database before doing SP-remove?

Tags: site-collection, sql

I'm currently testing doing some stuff on a site collection with a console app. I'd like to redo the test by deleting and then restoring the site collection, but I'm not sure if I need to delete something in Sql before? Any best practice tips?

Answer (score 3):

Do not remove the site collection from the database! Just remove it via the GUI (Site settings -> Delete site) or use the PowerShell cmdlet `Remove-SPSite` (outlined [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607948.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). This will make sure it is deleted the right way